# SilverStripe remove ModelAdmin search

Tags: php, silverstripe

Is there a way to remove the search functionality for `ModelAdmin` pages?

For now I'm using CSS, but there should be a better solution.

```css
#filters-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WE talked on IRC, but just for the record let me put this out here:

There has always been the possibility to overwrite `public function SearchForm() { return false; }` and therefore remove the form. This however does not effect the #filters-button (3.4) or the sidebar (3.0-3.3).
So at this time, you do have to use CSS.

I have however just created a Pull Request to implement `$showSearchForm` which would work the same way as `$showImportForm`.

<s>https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/6237</s>
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/6309 (Re-raised Pull Request)

This will probably be merged into <s>3.4.2</s> 3.5.0, once that is in you can do:

```
class FooBarAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    private static $url_segment = 'foobar';
    private static $managed_models = ['Foo', 'Bar'];
    public $showImportForm = false;
    public $showSeachForm = false;
    # or if you just want to disable seach for Foo but not Bar:
    #public $showSeachForm = ['Bar'];
}
```

Comment: Today 3.5.0-rc2 (release candidate 2) has been tagged, and my pull request has been merged just in time. So it will be in 3.5 once which will probably be released in the next weeks.

You can already use it if you just require "~3.5" (that's equal to >=3.5,<4) in composer (composer will install RC until there is a stable 3.5 release)